# Topic exceed maximum error with using HMS Push Kit?

Tags: push, huawei-mobile-services

Issues encountered when using HMS Push Kit
While I coded my app using HMS push kit, I met the following Issues:
Crash logs :

- subscribe_topic, 907122034: topic exceed
- subscribe_topic, 907122035: topic send error
  It leads to a few questions:

1. What is ERROR_TOPIC_EXCEED (2000) really about?
2. Does it mean that client has subscribed too many times to the specified topic?

Answer (score 0):

A maximum of 2000 topics can be subscribed to for one app instance.

If you exceed this limit, you will get the "topic exceed" error you mentioned. In this case, you should either delete some topics or divide them into batches if you want to use 2000+ topics.

If the client application tries to subscribe to the same topic more than once, no error is returned, it is not ignored, and it re-subscribes normally.

Pls  refer to [Huawei PUSH KIT](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/android-topic-based-sending-0000001050040114) and [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging)